# How do you grab the application specific window handle in Chrome and Firefox and other Applications?

Tags: c#

I need the specific wHnd (Window Handle) for Application specific windows: Google Chrome/Firefox web page text (not form TextBoxes).  ListBoxes and System Tree's also do NOT return using the normal calls(Code snippet below).  Another application specific window that would be GREATLY beneficial would be the Visual Studios Code windows (more than just the Code window would always help more !!)..  Thanks for the help.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class WindowUtils {
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    IntPtr ProcessId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr AttachThreadInput(
    IntPtr idAttach, 
    IntPtr idAttachTo,
    bool fAttach);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

public IntPtr GetFocusedControl() {
    IntPtr activeWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

    IntPtr activeWindowThread = 
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
    IntPtr thisWindowThread =
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);

    AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, true);
    IntPtr focusedControlHandle = GetFocus();
    AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThread, thisWindowThread, false);

    return focusedControlHandle;
}
}
```

Comment: What is "application specific window handle"?

Comment: All applications have multiple Form Controls inside them, each of those controls are application specific window handles.. for some reason you can pickup on TextBoxes, RichTextBoxes, but not much else.

Comment: @yumyum You can click delete yourself. Until then, it's better un-butchered.